# CSS pre-wrap property

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've a question about the `pre-wrap: pre;` property. We have a H2 tag within a title like:

```
Teachers and students are the same
```

We want to achieve that the words `the same` come on line two. For example:

```
Teachers and students
are the same
```

Unfortunately the `pre-wrap:pre;` is not working well as we expect on mobile, then we get the text outside of the screen. Is this property the right solution, and how to fix it well on mobile?

Comment: Why not just use a br tag?

Comment: I totally forgot that <br> tag for some reason, I thought that it was a dirty fix but it is actually working great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a *non-breaking space* `&nbsp;` in between 'the same' text, but only if you have control over the text shown and the `width`.

```css
h2 {
  width: 380px;
}
```

```html
<h2>"Teachers and students are the&nbsp;same"
</h2>
```

Comment: yes thank you I totally forget the &nbsp;